# unable to connect to unc location using jcifs

Tags: java, unc, jcifs

I have some remote locations that falls under same domain.When i access the remote location from windows then it opens without asking for credentials.But if i aceess the location using java code (jcifs) then it gives me this exception

> jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad
>   password

Java code is

```
String path=convertToSmb(loc);
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth=new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(path, userName, passwd);
        SmbFile sFile=null;
        try {
            sFile=new SmbFile(path,auth);
            sFile.connect();
            boolean sFileExists = sFile.exists();
            logger.info("checkUNCLocation [END] with :: sfileExists :: "+sFileExists);
            return sFileExists;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            return UNCNetworkConnectionWrapper.connectUNCNetwork(loc, userName, passwd);
        }finally{

            sFile=null;
            //jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.disablePlainTextPasswords", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
        }
```

i tried deleting all connections using net use delete but windows still did not ask for credentials

Logging also shows correct credentials.
Please guide what should be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `userName` and the `password`??

How Windows doing it is by try to connect the server using the current credentials, If you are connected with your user and you are trying to connect to other machine in the same domain, the connection will succeed , because your credentials is valid in this Domain.

Try to use your own credentials to connect to "this" server.